# Forcing smoothness of regression coefficients

Tags: multiple-regression, references, regression-coefficients, smoothing, functional-data-analysis

I'm building regression models on spectral datasets: the predictors are the intensites of signal at the different frequencies. In this case the intensities at close frequency values are highly correlated, being part of the same signal peak. I was consequently expecting regression coefficients varying slowly with the frequency, but this is not the case for several regression methods including PLS, Ridge and Lasso.
I looked for regression methods that somehow force the coefficients to be smooth function of the frequency, but without success, so I'm asking if there is any.

In order not to make the question too vague I try to ask two specific questions:

1. Is there a regression method that uses a kind of penality, similar to that of the Ridge or Lasso regression, but involving the discrete derivatives of the regression coefficients instead of their values?
2. Is there a regression method that uses regression coefficients that are smooth function of the frequency (polynomial, spline, whatever)?

Please point to references.

Comment: Even if close frequencies take on similar values, could they not hold different information? If they hold different information in similar values, would not the coefficients have to be large? Also: You do have enough training data so differing coefficients are not due to overfitting?

Comment: @Bernhard. For what we know of our spectra, the information should the same for close frequencies: due to the same position of the same molecule. To be more precise, there is a certain small overlap among different signals. Maybe we don't have enough training data to exclude overfitting, but won't be smoothing of the coefficients a way to decrease the risk of overfitting?

Comment: I guess it would be a relief against overfitting to some extend. I haven't got an answer to the point of your question and hope, somebody has. Nevertheless I think it would be good to know, what exactly the problem is and if it is overfitting, one might think of other ways to control that.

Comment: I'm not totally sure that I fully understand the problem you're solving, but I wanted to mention that there is such thing as a so-called "smooth lasso" that penalizes successive regression coefficients for being too different. Maybe it can be helpful for you? https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.4885

Comment: An example very close to yours is in (second edition, and probably first) of [*The Elements of Statistical Learning*](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/ElemStatLearn/)  5.2.3: Example:Phoneme Recognition

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Thanks. This is exactly an example for point 2 in my question. I think that it is also an example of the Functional Data Analysis approach suggested by Manuel in his answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want something simple, I would look at (weighted) fused LASSO or similarly ridge-style regression. Suppose you have

$$ y \in \mathbf{R}^{T\times 1} \text{ response} \qquad X_{k} \in \mathbf{R}^{T\times 1} \text{ where } k\in\{1, \dots, K\} \text{ $k$th covariate }$$

You want some smoothness of coefficients that should be close, ie if $k$th and $j$th covariates should have coefficients that are close in some norm. For simplicity, assume chain-type structure, ie $1$st covariate is related to $2$nd, $2$nd to $3$rd ect. The estimators you may want to look at are

$$ \hat\beta \in \underset{\beta\in \mathbf{R}^{K}}{ \text{arg min}}\|y-X\beta\|^2_T + 2\lambda_1 \|\beta\|_1 + 2\lambda_2 \|D \beta\|_1 \quad \text{fused LASSO}$$

or

$$ \hat\beta \in \underset{\beta\in \mathbf{R}^{K}}{ \text{arg min}}\|y-X\beta\|^2_T + 2\lambda \|D \beta\|^2_2 \quad \text{Ridge-type}$$

where

$$
D  = \begin{pmatrix}
0 &  0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 \\
1 & -1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 1 & -1 & \dots & 0 & 0  \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 1 & -1  \\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

and $\|u\|^2_T = \langle u,u \rangle/T$. You may also add LASSO-type constraint to the second estimator to impose sparsity on top of $\ell_2$ constraint (you will get something like the elastic net). As usual, Ridge (without additional LASSO constraint) has closed form (provided that $D$ satisfies some simple conditions).

The first reference for the fused LASSO I would look at is: https://web.stanford.edu/group/SOL/papers/fused-lasso-JRSSB.pdf. There are many efficient solvers in many software packages for such type of problems.

Lastly, you may use correlation as weights for $k$ and $j$ pair of covariates and adjust the penalty term accordingly. Define $\rho_{k,j}$ as a simple correlation between two covariates. You probably want to have a correlation between two consecutive covariates, i.e. $\rho_{k,k+1}$, $k \in \{1,\dots, K-1\}$, and you want to take the absolute value of correlations. Then, redefine the $D$ matrix as

$$
D  = \begin{pmatrix}
0 &  0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 \\
|\rho_{1,2}| & -|\rho_{2,1}| & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & |\rho_{2,3}| & -|\rho_{3,2}| & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & |\rho_{K-1,K}| & -|\rho_{K,K-1}|  \\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

where $\rho_{k,k-1} = \rho_{k-1,k}$, of course. Then you take into account the relative strength between each pair of covariates, which can help.

You have to try several estimators and see what works best for your dataset.

For your second question, maybe you can use the dictionary of functions, say $W$, to approximate the weight function of different frequencies you have in your dataset. So, if your predictors are $Z_{j,k}$, for $j\in \{1,\dots,J\}$, define $X_{k}=(Z_{1,k},\dots,Z_{J,k})W$, and run the usual regression of $y$ on $X$. $W$ can be splines for example. I'm not sure if it makes sense to smooth coefficients in this case.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think that you answered to point 1. Do you have also suggesions for point 2? Also: can you provide a reference for fused Ridge? In the last part do you mean to use correlation to fill the matrix D? How precisely? Thank you very much.

Comment: 1. I updated my answer, but I don't have much to say about this question... 
2. I don't have a good reference for fused Ridge, and don't think such exists. But as far as computations go, it is straightforward, you just need to adjust $\lambda I$ term in Ridge estimator. 
3. Updated my answer.

Comment: The comment by Jake Westfal above actually answers the question on reference for fused ridge (what is called smoothed lasso), where authors show statistical guarantees for such method. And the answer by Manuel below is more general....

Comment: One of the earlier references I have seen on fused ridge penalties in the literature is Goeman, J. J. (2008). Autocorrelated logistic ridge regression for prediction based on proteomics spectra. Statistical Applications in Genetics and Molecular Biology, 7(2). See also arxiv.org/pdf/1509.09169.pdf for some very good lecture notes on ridge regression & all its variants.

Answer (score 4):

This is the motivation for  [Functional Data Analysis.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_data_analysis)

I will describe the functional covariate and scalar response linear model which is just one of many many possible models.

Asumes pairs $(x, y)$ where $$ y = \int_{a}^{b} \beta(t)x(t) \, dt + \varepsilon$$
Here $x$ is a random curve, y a scalar response and $\beta$ an unknown function that links both variables.

There are many approachs to estimate $\beta$ but one that is a direct solution to your problem is finding $\alpha$ in a suitable finite dimentional space such that minimices
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \left(y_i - \int_a^b \alpha(t) x_i(t) \,dt\right)^2 + \lambda \| \alpha^{(m)} \|^2 $$

Usually $m=2$ so you penalize roughness of your function. Higher values of $\lambda$ will give smoother estimations.

Usually one does not observe curves but a discretized version of them.  If $(t_k, x_i (t_k))$ are your values for frecuency an intensity $1\leq k\leq p$ and $1 \leq i \leq n$ then you may estimates your curves with splines or any other method of your choice. A great plus of this method is that you do not need to have all your observations in the same grid. You can actually have different $p_i$. An other important aspect to consider is that these method ares specially designed to bypass the high correlation between the $x_i(t_k)$ $x_i(t_{k+s})$. Also using a suitable finite dimentional space make optimization tasks simple.

A great book for studing this models is [Functional Data Analysis by Ramsay And Silverman.](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=mU3dop5wY_4C&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false).

There are also R packages such as fda and fda.usc.

Comment: This is very useful. I will add that there is a CRAN Task View on this topic: https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/FunctionalData.html.