# Right way to bin the data-Fitting Voigt profiles to spectroscopy data

Tags: count-data, poisson-regression, curve-fitting, binning, functional-data-analysis

I have some measurements of the rate of a physical process versus energy. For each energy I have a number of counts and a measurement time associated to it. However, the step (in energy) at which the measurements are made is very small and also the measurement time is small, hence just plotting a rate vs energy for each measured energy doesn't really work (many energy entries also have zero counts).

I would like to bin the data such that to obtain a reasonable shape of the spectrum for a fit (I also have something of the order 10,000 measurements, so doing directly a log-likelihood would not work). Assuming that the error on the x axis (energy) is negligible and the errors are Poisson, how should I choose the right bin size? The function that I need to fit is the sum of 4 Voigt profiles plus a constant background, so it is highly nonlinear.

Also, how should I choose the x and y for each bin (to use for the fit)? For the y, I think the right way to do is to add all the counts in that bin (N) and all the measuring time (T) and give the rate (y value) as N/T with the error $\sqrt{N}/T$. For x axis, I could just use the average of the energy values in that bin. However, for some energies the measuring time is higher than for others. Should I use a time weighted average in order to get the x of the bin?

Comment: Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Is the measurement time equal at each energy level? I will assume so below, if not, the log of measurement time could be used as an offset in the Poisson regression below.

There is no need to bin the data before fitting, smoothing could be done as part of the fitting. You can model the counts via a regression spline, in R something like

```
library(splines)
mod0 <- glm(count ~ ns(energy, df=5), family=poisson, data=your_data_frame)
```

Alternatively, you can try a gam (generalized additive model), which will determine the degrees of freedom of the smooth from the data. Something like:

```
library(mgcv)
mod1 <- gam(count ~ s(energy), family=poisson, data=your_data_frame)
```

Alternatively, you could look into functional data analysis. There are similar posts on this site, a recent one is [Forcing smoothness of regression coefficients](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/437066/forcing-smoothness-of-regression-coefficients).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am new to statistic and I have never used regression spline before (also I can't read that code, as I use Python, not R), does this work (in practice) for any function? I need to fit the sum of 4 Voigt profiles to my data, so it is a function of around 20 parameters, highly non-linear. Also the measuring times are not equal.

Comment: Can you add this details to tour question? I Will add More when at home

Comment: The sum of four Voigt profiles changes the nature of the question, as it is no longer nonparametric. The same approach with Poisson regression should be used (as you say the errors are Poisson), but as measuring times are unequal, the log of measuring time should be added as an offset. I will try to add this to the answer, but first must read up on Voigt profiles ... I don't know much Python, so cannot advice on how to do it there. But certainly must be possible.

Comment: I'm not using python, but this could be of interest:   https://www.researchgate.net/publication/320707640_BayesVP_a_Bayesian_Voigt_profile_fitting_package

Comment: Some R packages that could be useful: `RcppFaddeeva`, `serrsBayes`. You want to fit sum of 4 Voigt profiles because there is 4 peaks in the spectrum? Could you add to the post a sample spectrum plot?

Comment: Modeling directly the Voigt profiles could be done via *nonlinear* Poisson regression, but so far I did not get the R `gnm` package to work. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59493784/writing-a-custom-model-for-gnm-package-but-need-a-function-not-in-derivative-ta